# Collision detection of 3d objects in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am working on a infinite runner game, where 3d objects are involved - A rover and some obstacles, that move on a terrain. The game is made using p5.js WebGL functionality. I have almost completed the game, but the game should end when the rover hits any obstacle. I just want to know if I can detect the collision of both the 3d objects(the rover is a plane, and the obstacle is custom loaded model) and end the game...Simply, I want to know whether collision detection in WebGL is feasible, and if so how?
Please help me out on the same.
Thank you.

Comment: It's feasible, but details of your game matter. Please provide a [mcve] of your code attempt and ask a specific question about where you're stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, indeed, you'd post a minimal sketch of your attempt at detecting the collision: something to make it easier for other to contribute (without making to many wild guesses on your behalf).

One idea is to check if the bounding box of the 3d model (defined by it's minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ values) intersects with the plane (or the bounding box of the plane if it's simpler to keep things consistent). It won't be 100% accurate, depending on the loaded model (we don't even know what that is is), but it's a decent initial step.

For more accuracy a convex hull would be handy. If computing that from scratch in p5.js might prove difficult, perhaps you could use the same 3D editor to export the model to also generate a convex hull of the original model and export that to be used as simpler collision mesh.

Additionally, even through more advanced, you can look into using a physics engine such as [ammo.js](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/) to handle the heavy collision math (and more) for you. (checkout [the vehicle demo](https://rawcdn.githack.com/kripken/ammo.js/99d0ec0b1e26d7ccc13e013caba8e8a5c98d953b/examples/webgl_demo_vehicle/index.html)).